# Yammer embed does not load on IE 10 for SP2013

Tags: sharepoint-2013, yammer

We are getting error on using the Yammer embed on IE10.
Using Sharepoint 2013 (oslo masterpage - ootb) and added a content editor with the following code, note this is working if you have IE11 but NOT on IE10.

```
<script src="https://assets.yammer.com/assets/platform_embed.js"</script>
<div id="embedded-feed" style="height:530px;width:320px;"></div>
<script> 
  yam.connect.embedFeed({
  "config": {
  "use_sso": false,
  "header": false,
  "footer": false,
  "showOpenGraphPreview": false,
  "defaultToCanonical": false,
  "hideNetworkName": false
},
"container": "#embedded-feed"
});
</script>
```

This was working a while ago and now it doesnt.
Is there any workaround without forcing the IE mode to IE11?
Reason is if we are to use IE11 a lot of work needs to be done on the site :(

Thanks.

Comment: What error are you getting? Providing more detail will help get you an answer. Test Embed outside of SharePoint using www.yammer.com/widget and www.yammer.com/widget/configure as well.